# Factory injection with interface and concrete type parameter

Tags: c#, autofac

I have the following interface and class

```
public interface IService{};
public class ServiceImp:IService {};
```

And I have the following classes that consume the service

```
public class ServiceProvider
{
   public ServiceProvider(Func<double, IService> service, double age)
   {
   }
}

public class ServiceProviderB
{
   public ServiceProviderB(Func<double, ServiceImp> service, double age)
   {
   }
}
```

The way I register now for `IService` and `ServiceImp` is as such:

```
builder.Register<Func<double, IService>>(c=> age => new ServiceImp (age));
builder.Register<Func<double, ServiceImp >>(c=> age => new ServiceImp (age));
```

I don't like it because it seems to me like double work. I know how to use `AsSelf()` and `AsImplementedInterfaces()` *for registration of actual instances*, so that I'll have only 1 registration statement, and not two. But in this case, I'm dealing with functors, not actual type instances.

How can I do the Autofac registration so that the above two Register statements can be merged into one?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer is to just let Autofac use [the built-in relationship types](https://autofac.readthedocs.io/en/latest/resolve/relationships.html) rather than registering your own functions.

```cs
public class UnitTest1
{
    [Fact]
    public void Repro()
    {
        var builder = new ContainerBuilder();

        // Just register the type, not functions.
        builder.RegisterType<Implementation>().AsSelf().AsImplementedInterfaces();
        var container = builder.Build();

        // Autofac will handle creation of the Func<T> factories.
        var interfaceFactory = container.Resolve<Func<double, IService>>();
        var implementationFactory = container.Resolve<Func<double, Implementation>>();

        // Profit!
        var service = interfaceFactory(12);
        Assert.Equal(12, service.Age);

        var impl = implementationFactory(24);
        Assert.Equal(24, impl.Age);
    }

    public interface IService
    {
        double Age { get; }
    }

    public class Implementation : IService
    {
        public Implementation(double age)
        {
            this.Age = age;
        }
        public double Age { get; }
    }
}
```